# Understanding terms for h-index calculation

Tags: python, excel, calculation

I'm trying to create a h-index calculator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-index#Calculation) for my research citations but am getting stumped by how to represent the maths in code form (not my forte sadly). Here is the calculation from wiki:

h index(f) = [image]

What does max min mean when side by side? I can't seem to find anything about it online. I think that the 'i' underneath the max represents the start of the range of values which are used in the equation. I've looked multiple websites for simplified/more elegant calculations than a load of IF statements but to no avail.

Sorry if this isn't posted on the right type of forum. I'm not asking someone to write the code but just want help understanding how to represent the different terms in either python or excel.

Thanks for any help

Comment: The idea is, for each value of `i`, you take the minimum of i and f(i), then get the max (for all the i's)  of these values. Note that your data must be sorted first so that f is decreasing, as well explained in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_h_index(citations):
    citations = sorted(citations, reverse=True)
    for idx, item in enumerate(citations, 1):
        if item < idx:
            break
    return idx - 1

citations = [10,8,5,4,3]
h_index = get_h_index(citations)
print(h_index)
# yields 4

other_citations = [25,8,5,3,3]
h_index = get_h_index(other_citations)
print(h_index)
# yields 3
```

Comment: You can also give a start value of 1 to `enumerate`: `for idx, item in enumerate(citations, 1):   if citations[idx] < idx:`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille in this case I would not do that because then you would have to access citations[idx-1] inside the for loop, so the gain from 1-indexing is offset by the increased complexity inside of the loop. Ordinarily, I'm all for 1-indexing enumeration though.

Comment: Oh, I had misread your code and copy-pasted as it was... You shouldn't use `citations[idx]` at all anyway, because it is `item`. So, the way to go is: `for idx, item in enumerate(citations, 1):   if item < idx:`. That's the whole point of `enumerate`.

Comment: Ahh, right, you're still returning idx - 1 which is a bit awkward, but perhaps a minor improvement. I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special meaning in maxmin You're seeking to maximise the minimum of *f(i)* and *i*.

For each value of *i*, you compute *f(i)* and *i* and take smaller (minimum) of these two values. If we call this minimum *g(i)*, we're looking for the largest value of *g(i)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the h-index, you can just use the `scholarmetrics` module.
https://scholarmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/